# Ionic: How do i load only 1 image from my json file?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs, ionic-framework

I've managed to load all my images from my json file into the application but i would only like 1 image to be loaded. I'm using ng-repeat which is why it keeps repeating itself. What do i replace ng-repeat with so it only shows the first image?

Here's my code.

Html:

```
<div ng-click="onClick()">
  <i class="ion-images"></i>
</div>
<a ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <ion-scroll direction="x">
    <img on-hold="onHold()" ng-repeat="image in data" ng-src="{{image.image}}" />
  </ion-scroll>
</a>
```

js:

.controller("Ctrl", function($scope, $http, $ionicModal) {

```
$scope.data = [];

$http.get('')
  .success(function(data) {
    $scope.data = data;
    window.localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(data));
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want display only first element from your array you don't have use ng-repeater, you can access it using array index ie:

```
ng-src="{{data.under9s[0].image}}
```

Please see working demo below:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data = [];

  $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/4tutm')
    .success(function(data) {
      $scope.data = data;
      window.localStorage.setItem("images", JSON.stringify(data));
    })
    .error(function(error) {
      if (window.localStorage.getItem("images") !== undefined) {
        $scope.data = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("images"));
      }
    });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
  <script>
    document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');
  </script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.3/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.3"></script>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
  <ion-scroll direction="x">
    <img on-hold="onHold()" ng-src="{{data.under9s[0].image}}" ng-click="showImages($index)" class="image-list-thumb" />
  </ion-scroll>
</body>

</html>
```